# Canonical injection is compatible with induced equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on a set $E$, let $A$ be a subset of $E$, let $j : A \to E$ be the canonical injection, and let $R_A$ be the equivalence relation induced by $R$ on $A$ (that is, the inverse image of $R$ under $j$). According to Bourbaki:

> The injection $j$ is obviously compatible with the relations $R_A$ and $R$. (*Theory of Sets*, p. 119)

Why?

Let $g$ be the canonical projection of $A$ onto $R/A$. If the statement above is true, and if $g(x) = g(x^\prime)$, then $j(x) = j(x^\prime)$. That is, $x = x^\prime$. Therefore $g(x) = \{x\}$. But that isn't true in general.

What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything in your assumptions that requires $j(x)=j(x')$. What compatibility requires is just that

> If $x\mathrel{R_A} x'$ then $j(x)\mathrel R j(x')$

which is obviously true. Or, equivalently,

> If $g(x)=g(x')$ then $g(j(x))=g(j(x'))$

which is pretty much vacuous because $j$ is by definition the identity on $A$.

Comment: A function $f$ on $A$ is compatible with $R_A$ if and only if $g(x) = g(x^\prime)$ implies $f(x) = f(x^\prime)$ (p. 118).

Comment: @RandyRanderson: That doesn't sound right. The definition of "compatible with $R$" should be something that mentions the letter $R$ somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps you have a secondary definition of "compatible with $R$ and $S$" with two relations mentioned?

Comment: $R_A$ is implicit in the canonical projection $g$. Bourbaki defines $f$ to be compatible with $R_A$ if $(y = f(x) \text{ and } R_A[x,x^\prime]) \implies y = f(x^\prime)$. That is, $f$ is constant on the equivalence classes of $R_A$.

Comment: @Randy: However your quote does not say "compatible with $R_A$", but instead "compatible with the relations $R_A$ and $R$". That means that a definition that only defines the meaning "compatible with [a single relation]" does not apply here.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I thought he meant "$j$ is compatible with $R_A$ and $j$ is compatible with $R$". Thanks.